# Customized Qt Assistant: Content not shown

Tags: xml, qt, documentation, qt-assistant

I intend to create a customized Qt Assistant for providing help in my own application.
I followed the Qt documentation on that topic. The table of contents and all keywords are available when I launch the assistant, but my content is not shown.

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong in this stripped down version?

**test.qhp:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QtHelpProject version="1.0">
  <namespace>test</namespace>
  <virtualFolder>doc</virtualFolder>

  <filterSection>
    <toc>
      <section title="test" ref="index.html">
      </section>
    </toc>

    <keywords>
      <keyword name="Test" ref="index.html"/>
    </keywords>

    <files>
      <file>index.html</file>
    </files>

  </filterSection>
</QtHelpProject>
```

**test.qhcp:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QHelpCollectionProject version="1.0">
  <assistant>
    <title>test</title>
    <!--     <applicationIcon>images/handbook.png</applicationIcon> -->
    <cacheDirectory>test/doc</cacheDirectory>

    <startPage>qthelp://test/doc/index.html</startPage>

    <aboutMenuText>
      <text>About test</text>
    </aboutMenuText>

    <enableDocumentationManager>false</enableDocumentationManager>
    <enableAddressBar>false</enableAddressBar>
    <enableFilterFunctionality>false</enableFilterFunctionality>
  </assistant>

  <docFiles>
    <generate>
      <file>
        <input>test.qhp</input>
        <output>test.qch</output>
      </file>
    </generate>
    <register>
      <file>test.qch</file>
    </register>
  </docFiles>
</QHelpCollectionProject>
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>index</h1>
    This is the index page
  </body>
</html>
```

I create the qhc file using `qcollectiongenerator test.qhcp -o test.qhc`

When I open the assistant using `assistant -collectionFile test.qhc`, I only see a blank page, instead of `index.html`'s content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by a bug in Qt Assistant: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-24110

The html code needs to be at least 512 bytes long.